# I have two 6 volts DC motors connected to L298N motor Driver. Do I need to use 12 Volts battery?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, battery

I have **two 6 volts DC motors** connected to **L298N motor Driver**. Do I need to use 12 Volts battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to use a (roughly) 6V battery. They are 6V motors, so they need a 6V battery.

However, you *do* need to sum the *currents* not the voltages. The battery must be able to provide *at least* the current required by *both* motors together.